# Oracle invalid identifier error 7

Tags: sql, oracle

I've looked at multiple questions that have been asked before but they don't seem to fix my problem. I keep getting an invalid identifier error with my following code:

```
SELECT C.VENDOR_ID, C.VENDOR_SITE_ID, C.AMOUNT, I.AMOUNT AS LINE_AMOUNT, C.BANK_AMOUNT_ID, C.BANK_ACCOUNT_NAME, 
    C.CHECK_DATE, C.CHECK_ID, C.CHECK_NUMBER, C.CURRENCY_CODE, C.PAYMENT_METHOD_LOOKUP_CODE, C.PAYMENT_TYPE_FLAG, 
    C.CHECKRUN_NAME, C.STATUS_LOOKUP_CODE, C.CLEARED_AMOUNT, C.CLEARED_DATE, C.CLEARED_BASE_AMOUNT, 
    C.CLEARED_EXCHANGE_RATE, C.CLEARED_EXCHANGE_DATE, C.EXCHANGE_RATE, C.EXCHANGE_DATE, C.CE_BANK_ACCT_USE_ID, 
    C.PAYMENT_METHOD_CODE, C.PARTY_ID, C.PARTY_SITE_ID, C.PAYMENT_DOCUMENT_ID, C.REMIT_TO_SUPPLIER_NAME, C.REMIT_TO_SUPPLIER_ID, 
    C.REMIT_TO_SUPPLIER_SITE_ID, I.INVOICE_ID, I.INVOICE_PAYMENT_ID, I.PERIOD_NAME, I.INVOICE_BASE_AMOUNT, I.PAYMENT_BASE_AMOUNT, 
    I.REVERSAL_FLAG, I.REVERSAL_INV_PMT_ID, S.ADDRESS_LINE1, S.ADDRESS_LINE_ALT, S.ADDRESS_LINE2, S.ADDRESS_LINE3, S.CITY, 
    S.STATE, S.ZIP, S.PROVINCE, S.COUNTRY 
FROM AP_CHECKS_ALL C
JOIN AP_INVOICE_PAYMENTS_ALL I
ON C.CHECK_ID = I.CHECK_ID
JOIN AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL S
ON C.VENDOR_SITE_ID = S.VENDOR_SITE_ID AND C.VENDOR_ID = S.VENDOR_ID
```

Comment: Please post the error message...

Comment: Please always include the exact error message in your post

Comment: `e-BS` should be clearly mentioned not just in the post, but should be included in the tags. If the tag  does not exist, should be created

Answer (score 1):

Check your column names.  It's `ADDRESS_LINES_ALT`, not `ADDRESS_LINE_ALT`.

Generally speaking, you will get an `ORA-00904: invalid identifier` when you attempt to select a column from a table that does not contain that column.  E.g.,

```
SELECT not_dummy FROM DUAL;

>>> ORA-00904: "NOT_DUMMY": invalid identifier
```

Comment: How in the world could you possibly know what his column name should be?  What you suggested isn't anywhere in the OP's question.

Comment: He's querying an Oracle e-BS database.  The table names and the columns in each are public knowledge.  My answer is correct.  He is getting `invalid identifier` because he is attempting to select a column that is not in his table.  `c.bank_amount_id` should also be `c.bank_account_id`.

Comment: Making a lot of assumptions here... I'm standing by my downvote until the OP clarifies his question.

Comment: I understand.  But to improve my own usefulness on S.O., answer this... even generally speaking, the OP stated: "I keep getting an invalid identifier error".  General answer: check your column names and make sure they really exist in the table.  Would that have been more appropriate?  You can get the table definition for `AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL` from Oracle's website, so what's wrong with giving the OP a more exact answer?

Comment: Matthew is right. His answer does not deserve to be down voted

Comment: The reason I downvoted was because your original answer just said to change one of the fields to something that was never mentioned in the OP's original question.  You made a lot of assumptions about their structure beyond the scope of the question.  Regardless of being right or wrong, the answer lacked any sort of explanation of how you arrived at the conclusion you did, and it certainly deserved a downvote in its previous state.  But your edit answers their question, so I'm reversing it.

Comment: @Siyual -- You are right: the answer is better now for having a more general explanation.  Thank you for your guidance.